# array to string conversion error in php when get data from another page

Tags: php

1.First Page :

```
<a href="EditBoq.php?id=<?php echo  $_REQUEST['numb'];  ?>&type=<?php echo $_REQUEST['wtype']; ?>"
```

transfer 2 variable in anchor tag.

2.Second Page :

```
$sql="select * from basicboq where  boqno = '".$_REQUEST['id']."' and SideType= '".$_REQUEST['type']."' ";
$req = mysql_query($sql)or die('error'.mysql_error());
```

when I print this boqno It's display error : array to string conversion.

Comment: when you are clicking on link what url comes in browser? can you paste that here? it seems like url in browser contain array

Comment: Please just give full description of your question and in query your argument is wrong while you are passing different arguments

Comment: Please stop using deprecated `mysql_` functions and also protect yourself from SQL injections, read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php